# How do I switch back and forth between Ubuntu Classic and Core

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, snap, ubuntu-core

To switch to Ubuntu Classic from core:

```
sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge
sudo classic
```

But how do I switch back to core?

I acknowledge that the purpose of Core is for IoT but Classic is not compiled for the Qualcomm DragonBoard 410c and I would like a GUI.

Comment: You can use the
    exit 
command to exit to the terminal over ssh but how do I disable it all together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exit` will put the terminal back into *Ubuntu Core* mode from *Classic*.

Very much like exiting an ssh connection.